# Deploying a Maven web project on Jetty

Tags: java, eclipse, maven-2, jetty

when I try to run my project on Jetty I get this exception:

**java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Default**

The full stack:

```
Launching Jetty with port 8080, context / and webapp path src/main/webapp
2011-07-19 16:49:56.832:INFO::Logging to STDERR via org.mortbay.log.StdErrLog
2011-07-19 16:49:56.841:INFO::jetty-6.1.26
2011-07-19 16:49:57.181:WARN::EXCEPTION 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Default
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:401)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:363)
    at org.mortbay.util.Loader.loadClass(Loader.java:91)
    at org.mortbay.util.Loader.loadClass(Loader.java:71)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Holder.doStart(Holder.java:73)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.doStart(ServletHolder.java:242)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:736)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:140)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1282)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:518)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:499)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:224)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at   net.sourceforge.eclipsejetty.launch.JettyLauncherMain.launch(JettyLauncherMain.java:67)
at     net.sourceforge.eclipsejetty.launch.JettyLauncherMain.main(JettyLauncherMain.java:50)
2011-07-19 16:49:57.184:INFO:/:Unavailable javax.servlet.UnavailableException: Default
2011-07-19 16:49:57.185:WARN::failed Default: java.lang.NullPointerException
2011-07-19 16:49:57.283:WARN::Failed startup of context     org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext@5f1eb199{/,src/main/webapp}
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.lang.Class.isAssignableFrom(Native Method)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.doStart(ServletHolder.java:256)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:736)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:140)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1282)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:518)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:499)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:224)
   at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
   at     net.sourceforge.eclipsejetty.launch.JettyLauncherMain.launch(JettyLauncherMain.java:67)
at  net.sourceforge.eclipsejetty.launch.JettyLauncherMain.main(JettyLauncherMain.java:50)
2011-07-19 16:49:57.294:INFO::Started SocketConnector@0.0.0.0:8080
```

I says that it cannot load my class Default.java (the only class in my project).

Here is my structure **(UPDATED)**:

[image]

And I deploy my project using the Jetty plugin.
To run it, I right click my project and select Debug As-> Debug Configurations... and I select the one that is setup below:

[image]

Here is also my web.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-   app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>ServletWeb-Test</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>Default</display-name>
    <servlet-name>Default</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>Default</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>Default</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>/Default</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

I am running out of idea and I can't find why I get this error.
I someone could help me, I would gladly appreciate it!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to put your Java class files in src/main/java, not src/main/resources. Files in resources are not compiled, as they are not supposed to be source code. Generally you'd put xml descriptor files, image files, etc in resources.

The content of src/main/resources will be copied into your target folder when eclipse/maven will build your project.

Comment: Also, you shouldn't put classes in the default package. Some containers and other technologies don't handle the default package well. I'm not sure if Jetty is one of them.

Comment: @Jon7 Hum that's weird. When I did this, I right-clicked on src/main and added a java class. Looks like it was put automatically in /ressource... Why is that?
Ryan: Noted. I'll move my class in a named package. Thanks.

Comment: @Tigel I'm not really sure... Maybe m2eclipse is acting up... that plugin is always a good scapegoat :)

Comment: Sadly, it doesn't seem to be the problem. I updated my project structure. See the updated question :)

Comment: Ok I got it. I forgot to edit the <servlet-class> tag content in my web.xml file to reflect the new package structure. Should be packageName.Default instead of just Default. Thanks for your help! :)